# TypeError at /admin/registration/registrationprofile/1/

Tags: django

I am getting the error in the title when going into the admin site to activate a new user. I am using django-inspectional-registration from https://github.com/lambdalisue/django-inspectional-registration. I set everything up according to the quick start guide here https://django-inspectional-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quicktutorials.html.

In my debug it also states get_inline_instances() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) from django/contrib/admin/options.py

I understand what the error means and all but I just don't know how I should fix this?

I am using django 1.5.1.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the library doesn't work with Django 1.5. There are open issues about this on the project's GitHub page. Since the project hasn't been updated for several months, you might have to dig into the code and fix it yourself.

Update: it looks like those issues have been fixed. If you reinstall the latest version it will hopefully work for you now.

Comment: Thanks, I see this now. Is there any account mgmt stuff out there that lets an admin set up a user, sends an email then user is required to activate and create password after and no password initially?

Comment: I don't know whether there are any other similar packages that do what you are looking for.

Comment: The author has updated the code with fixes for this issue.